# How to makeTitle as an optional in docusign

Tags: docusignapi

My requirement is to make Title as an optional. User can either enters the Title or not but I dont see any options for this. I can see optional signature(SignHereOptional) and optional Initals(InitialHereOptional) but not other values as optional. I see only the below values for Type.

InitialHere, SignHere, FullName, FirstName, LastName, EmailAddress, Company, Title, DateSigned, InitialHereOptional, EnvelopeID, Custom, SignerAttachment, SignHereOptional, Approve or Decline.

Your help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Balaji.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the **required** property of a titleTab object will control whether or not the Title text box is a required or optional field for the recipient during their signing session.

Here's a (partial) example of a "create/send Envelope" request that specifies the Title tab is optional (required=false) for the recipient:

```
POST https://{{env}}.docusign.net/restapi/{{version}}/accounts/{{acctId}}/envelopes

{
    "emailSubject":"Contracts for signature",
    "emailBlurb":"Please sign the contracts ASAP. Thank you!",
    "recipients": {
        "signers" : [{
            "email": "adamsemail@outlook.com",
            "name": "Adam Adamson",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "routingOrder": "1",
            "tabs": {
                "titleTabs": [{
                    "documentId": "1",
                    "pageNumber": "1",
                    "recipientId": "1",
                    "xPosition": "30",
                    "yPosition": "100",
                    "tabLabel": "Title",
                    "required": false
                }]      
            }
          }
        ]
    }
    "status": "sent"
}
```

For more information about Title tab properties, see the **Tab Types and Parameters** section of the DocuSign REST API Guide (http://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/REST_API_Guide_v2.pdf).  Specifically, see the **Title Tab** section (p384-387) for a description of all properties for a **Title** tab.